# How to disable power button turning on flashlight while screen off in Android?

Tags: settings, buttons, flashlight, samsung-bixby

I have a galaxy S20+, and multiple times per day, when I pick up my phone or pull it out of my pocket and turn the screen on, the flashlight comes on too. It's very annoying.

The flashlight is supposed to turn on if the screen is off and you hold the power button. But often it happens immediately when tapping quickly to turn on the screen, instead of waiting for holding the button.

I don't know why or how this happens. If I try to make it happen, I can't. When I try to replicate the problem, the flashlight won't turn on unless I explicitly turn off the screen and then hold the power button for a second or so, like it's supposed to. The problem just happens when I don't want it to and I can't figure out how to fix.

Half the day my flashlight is on without me realizing, because it happens so much. When I'm at the gym I will often see the flashlight on through my pocket. It's so annoying. Often it shines into my eyes and hurts.

I've looked through all the system settings intensely many times. I can't find any setting. Nothing in the side key has any effect.

I disabled Automate and Button Mapper, but still it happens, so it's not caused by those apps.

I looked through Firefds Kit and Gravity Box, but no setting is there. After months being annoyed by this and unable to solve, I'm coming here in hopes someone can help.

Button Mapper can remap my volume key to do the same thing, so I really just want to fully disable the power key from turning on flashlight while screen off, to solve the problem.

How can I do that? I'm rooted and willing to try anything.

--

Update I found out that it happens only when the phone has been sitting or in my pocket and is picked up and try to turn the screen on at the same time, and it turns on the flashlight. Haven't figured out how to solve it yet.

Comment: "*The flashlight is supposed to turn on if the screen is off and you hold the power button.*" for those who are not familiar with Samsung devices and their customization, did you mean there is a built-in setting for that? Also, are you using a custom ROM?

Comment: I'm using the factory Samsung ROM that came with the phone (OneUI). I do believe that this is a built-in feature. I don't recall enabling it and if I did, I have no idea where it was created. I did do a bunch of customization when I got it, but I can't find anything.